# Vue 3 Composition API data() function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Reading the [composition api documentation](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html) for Vue 3, I didn't quite understand how the new Composition API works. Could you please explain where the `data()` function has gone? And if it is no longer used what to use instead?

**Updated 23.10.2021:** The documentation in the link has been updated and expanded to include a mention of the `data()` in the Composition API introduction, so this question is now deprecated.

Comment: It hasn't gone. It's just compulsory to define `data` as a function, not just an object.

Comment: @MattEllen i mean if you look in Options API docs https://vuejs.org/v2/api/, you can find it on the left in the table of contents, but the documentation for Сomposition API lacks any mention of it https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html That's what confused me.

Comment: [This article](https://dev.to/alvarosaburido/how-to-migrate-your-library-from-vue2-to-vue3-1h81) shows the essential differences. As I said, the difference with `data` is that it can't be a plain object, it has to be a function.

Comment: @MattEllen `data` has always had to be a function (at least in Vue 2), and while Vue 3 still supports the Options API which includes the `data` method, the Composition API does not include `data()`.

Comment: @RobertNubel not at all. In Vue2 `data` has only had to be a function in `components` in the main app it can be a bare object.

Comment: @MattEllen ah -- I'm assuming OP is referring to data() method for building a component, rather than the data prop passed when instantiating Vue. You're correct on the latter.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Under the new Composition API, all of the variables that you previously defined in `data()` are just returned from your `setup()` function as normal variables with reactive values. For example, a Vue 2.0 component that had a data function like so:

```
data() {
  return {
    foo: 1,
    bar: { name: "hi" }
  }
}
```

becomes this `setup()` function in Vue 3:

```
setup() {
  const foo = ref(1);
  const bar = reactive({ name: "hi" });

  return { foo, bar }
}
```

The `ref` helper wraps a non-object value for reactivity, and `reactive` wraps an object. This is exposing the underlying principles of Vue more clearly than the old way, where the wrapping happened "magically" behind the scenes, but will behave the same otherwise. What I like about it personally is that your `setup()` function can build up your object on the go while keeping related things together, allowing it to tell a cohesive story and not require jumping around to different sections.

Comment: Also you can still access the variables returned by `setup()` in the Options API using `this.foo` for example.

Answer (score 13):

The composition is the new feature comes with Vue 3  and as a plugin for Vue 2, it doesn't replace the old option api but they could be used together in the same component.

The composition api compared to option api :

1. Gather the logic functionalities into reusable pieces of logic.
2. Use one option which the `setup` function which  *is executed before the component is created, once the props are resolved, and serves as the entry point for composition API's*.
3. Define your old data option as `ref` or `reactive` properties
4. computed and watch is defined as : `watch(...,()=>{...})` or `computed(()=>{...})`
5. Methods defined as plain javascript functions.
6. `setup` option used instead of created hook and it has as parameters the [`props`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#setup) and [`context`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#context)
7. Hooks like `mounted` could be used as `onMounted(()=>{...})`, [`learn more`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html)

With `script setup` syntax you could declare your reactive data using `ref`, `reactive` and  `computed` ...

```html
<script setup >
import { ref, reactive, computed } from 'vue'

const isActive = ref(false)
const user = reactive({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 })

const fullName = computed(() => user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName)

</script>
```