# Uncaught TypeError: dataOptions.call is not a function when load entry in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I upgrade the vue to 3.x `"vue": "^3.2.28"`, and then tweak the code initial app like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import template from './tpl.html';
import chromeCall from 'chrome-call';
import getOptions from '../public/default-options';
import {getTabLocation,isHostEnabled} from '../public/util';
import ST from './st';
import { createApp } from "vue";

export const appOptions = {
  el : 'app' ,
  template ,
  data : {
    _host : null ,
    canInject : false ,
    enabled : false
  } ,
  methods : {
    async switchEnable() {
      const {_host} = this.$data ,
        enabled = this.enabled = !this.enabled ,
        {excludeDomains} = await getOptions( 'excludeDomains' );

      if ( enabled ) {
        excludeDomains.splice( excludeDomains.indexOf( _host ) , 1 );
      } else {
        excludeDomains.push( _host );
      }
      return chromeCall( 'storage.local.set' , { excludeDomains } );
    }
  } ,
  components : {
    'st-box' : ST
  } ,
  async ready() {
    const locationObj = await getTabLocation();
    if ( locationObj ) {
      this.$data._host = locationObj.host;
      this.canInject = true;
      this.enabled = await isHostEnabled( locationObj );
    }
  }
};

/* istanbul ignore if */
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'testing' ) {
  window.onload = ()=> {
    setTimeout( ()=> {
      const app = createApp(appOptions);
      app.mount("app");
    }, 0 );
  };
}
```

I changed the app initial with Vue 3 way. The legacy initial was `new Vue()`, the new way was `createApp`. when I run this code, shows error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: dataOptions.call is not a function
    at applyOptions (commons1.js:4175:34)
    at finishComponentSetup (commons1.js:8531:9)
    at setupStatefulComponent (commons1.js:8443:9)
    at setupComponent (commons1.js:8373:11)
    at mountComponent (commons1.js:6296:13)
    at processComponent (commons1.js:6271:17)
    at patch (commons1.js:5872:21)
    at render (commons1.js:7015:13)
    at mount (commons1.js:5261:25)
    at Object.app.mount (commons1.js:10834:23)
```

what am I missing? what should I do to tweak my code to make it work?

Comment: But where is the code that deals with `dataOptions` and where you initialize the app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

finally I figure out the `dataOptions` was the data defined in `appOptions` that could not be understand by vue 3, in legacy vue, define data like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    foo: 1,
    bar: { name: "hi" }
  }
}
```

in vue 3, we should define like this:

```
setup() {
  const foo = ref(1);
  const bar = reactive({ name: "hi" });

  return { foo, bar }
}
```

more informatioin are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105088/vue-3-composition-api-data-function). I changed my code like this:

```
setup () {
    const host =null;
    const canInject =false;
    const enabled = false;
    return {host,canInject,enabled};
  } ,
```

Comment: This solved my day-long problem. Thank you!

Comment: While your way is recommended, for a quicker migrations it should be enough to convert the object `data: {...}` to a function like `data(){ return {...}; }`. See https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/data-option