# App built with vue CLI works perfectly, but when built with webpack appears to work but components functions aren't invoked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Been chasing this one for a little while, and managed to narrow it down to my webpack config. I have to use webpack for various reasons, so not using it isn't an option.

Basically I have a 'Hello World' Vue project. When I serve this app through `npx vue-cli-service serve` it works perfectly, and I get no issues. For reference I have a component that looks like this:

```
<template>
    <header class="app-header">
        {{ items }}
        {{ msg }}

        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
                {{ item.message }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'TheAppHeader',
    props: {
        msg: String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [{ message: 'Foo' }, { message: 'Bar' }],
        }
    },
    created() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('here');
      this.items.push({ message: 'FooBar' });
    }
}
</script>
```

that works perfectly when served this way - the template that uses it does so via `<TheAppHeader msg="test"></TheAppHeader>`. I see the `msg` come through, and I see the rendered `this.items` correctly (as well as the `console.log` coming through).

When I build the app via `npx webpack build` the app half works. I see the `msg` come through as before, but `this.items` does not render and the `console.log` does not come through. Neither `data()` nor `created()` are invoked. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my webpack config to create such an obscure issue? Is this common?

my `vue.config.js` looks like this

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map',
  }
})
```

and my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');


module.exports  = (env, argv) => { 
    let config = {
        target: 'web',
        mode: 'development',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                    generator: {
                        filename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
                    }
                },
                {  
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                    type: 'asset/resource',
                    generator: {
                        filename: 'fonts/[hash][ext][query]'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        babelParserPlugins: [
                          'jsx',
                          'classProperties',
                          'decorators-legacy'
                        ]
                      }
                },
                // this will apply to both plain `.js` files
                // AND `<script>` blocks in `.vue` files
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                // this will apply to both plain `.css` files
                // AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader'
                    ]
                },
            ],
        },
        entry: {
            vue:     './src/main.js'
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: true
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'distribution'),
            clean:true,
            publicPath: '/app/',
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './public/index.html'
            }),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                // Drop Options API from bundle
                __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
                // Enable devtools support
                __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__ : true,
                'process.env': {
                    BASE_URL: '"/"'
                  }
            }),
            new ESLintPlugin(
                {
                
                  extensions: [
                    '.js',
                    '.jsx',
                    '.vue'
                  ],
                  cache: true,
                  failOnWarning: false,
                  failOnError: true,
                  formatter: 'stylish',
                }),
        ],
    }
    return config;
}
```

Comment: Just confirmed it's nothing to do with using `serve` vs `build` - just built via the vue cli and served it via the same method for my webpack builds and same result.

Comment: Webpack config is hacky, there are "node_modules/" entries that aren't there normally. It's unknown why they are there in the first place. There shouldn't be separate Vue CLI and Webpack configs, it's either one or another. Vue CLI is a wrapper around Webpack. You can't extend Webpack in Vue CLI config. I wouldn't expect it to work correctly in its current state

Comment: @EstusFlask I am not trying to use both Vue CLI and WebPack. There is only two configs for the purpose of this test, hence why its pasted onto the hello world vue project. My actual application that only uses webpack and only has a `webpack.config.js` (where all of this is taken from, minus the `vue.config.js`) exhibits the exact same problem, `created()` and `data()` are never invoked.

They are both in one app to prove that there is a difference in the builds, even though the webpack build appears to work correctly.

Comment: The `node_modules/` entries are just lifted from trying to get webpack working off the back of how vue cli works (using `vue inspect` and taking the output). I will remove them and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: There seem to be contradictions. "When I build the app via npx webpack build the app half works." Then "even though the webpack build appears to work correctly". You may have hard time reproducing raw Webpack config from `vue inspect`, and `@vue/cli-service` isn't supposed to be used outside Vue CLI. I'd suggest to build the config from scratch. That `data` isn't triggered basically means that the comp isn't rendered. If there are no errors in the console, most likely because .vue wasn't correctly imported and there's no comp to render, so the problem is related to vue-loader.

Comment: @EstusFlask The component is rendered though, that's what I mean by "even though the webpack build appears to work correctly". The app half-functions. The components render. The vue routing works in my more-complicated-actual-app. Everything other than these functions being invoked.

Comment: @EstusFlask but yeah, you're right. Something is wrong with that webpack config. I just cut it back to a completely barebones config and it works fine.

Comment: its the `webpack.DefinePlugin` part. Commenting out `__VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,` fixes the problem. Are `created()` and `data()` part of the options API? EDIT: nevermind, yes they are. As per https://vuejs.org/api/

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of its role.

Comment: Luckily there's an eslint rule to force composition - I've set it up so the next unlucky soul in this project that attempts to copy & paste from an example that happens to use the options API will at least get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Component>.data()` and `<Component>.created()` are part of the Options API (as per [vuejs.org/api](https://vuejs.org/api)). By adding

```
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // Drop Options API from bundle
        __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
    }),
```

I was specifically disabling those functions from being called.

I should follow the composition way of doing it with that flag set, as per this answer: [Vue 3 Composition API data() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64105088/vue-3-composition-api-data-function) I need to stop using `data()` and use the `setup()` call instead.